# GTK+2.0 Combo Box - How to get the position of an entry?

Tags: c++, c, gtk

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
//Defined a comboBox like this 
combo = gtk_combo_box_new_text();

//Added entries like this 
gtk_combo_box_append_text(GTK_COMBO_BOX(combo), "string");

//How to get a particular entry deleted from the list of entries in the ComboBox combo?
```

How do I delete a particular entry in the comboBox? For example - The ComboBox dropdown has entries like "Foo", "Boo", "Hoo" etc. Now I want to select "Boo" and then remove it? How do I do that ?

//Segmentation fault while removal error

mcve -

```
fixed = gtk_fixed_new();
combo = gtk_combo_box_new_text();
gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), combo, 50, 50);
label = gtk_label_new("Rooms");
gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(fixed), label, 50, 30 );
gtk_table_attach_defaults (GTK_TABLE (table), fixed, 2, 3, 0, 2);
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(combo), "changed", G_CALLBACK(combo_selected), (gpointer) label);
```

In this callback function I just copy the current selection to a globally declared string. Next, in some other function I try to run this -

```
gtk_combo_box_remove_text (GTK_COMBO_BOX(combo), gtk_combo_box_get_active (GTK_COMBO_BOX(combo))); //statement where seg fault occurs
```

The gtk_combo_box_get_active gives me the appropriate index entry to be removed. Note - GtkWidget *combo is globally defined in the program.

Comment: I think you are looking for [gtk_combo_box_get_active](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkComboBox.html#gtk-combo-box-get-active) and [gtk_combo_box_text_remove](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkComboBoxText.html#gtk-combo-box-text-remove) (or [gtk_combo_box_remove_text](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkComboBox.html#gtk-combo-box-remove-text))

Comment: gtk_combo_box_remove_text (GTK_COMBO_BOX(combo), gtk_combo_box_get_active (GTK_COMBO_BOX(combo))); Gives me a seg fault

Comment: I assume gtk_combo_box_get_active returned -1, meaning there was no active item? Try removing one elemnt directy and check if you get a segfault that way, too(i.e. gtk_combo_box_remove_text(GTK_COMBO_BOX(combo),0))

Comment: gtk_combo_box_get_active is returning the appropriate index value but when I call  gtk_combo_box_remove_text it seg faults, even with a hardcoded index.

Comment: could you provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Its been a long time since i last worked with gtk, so i am a little unsure about this, but if i recall correctly, deleting the active entry triggers the "changed" signal, which - in your case - would try to delete another one, eventually resulting in some error. Does calling gtk_combo_box_remove_text from outside the signal handler cause the same error?

Comment: If I remove the signal listener, the deletion works fine.

Comment: In this case what i described seems to be the cause of your troubles. You could try avoiding it by explicitly checking the return value of gtk_combo_box_get_active in your signal handler each time it is called(and maybe check wheter it has any entries via [gtk_combo_box_get_has_entry](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkComboBox.html#gtk-combo-box-get-has-entry))
Does this solve your problem?

Comment: ok, i will compose an answer containing the information scattered across the comments ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id of the active(that is currently selected) entry in a combo box can be obtained via [gtk_combo_box_get_active](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkComboBox.html#gtk-combo-box-get-active) and it can be removed with help of [gtk_combo_box_text_remove](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkComboBoxText.html#gtk-combo-box-text-remove) or [gtk_combo_box_remove_text](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkComboBox.html#gtk-combo-box-remove-text)
(Depending on which version of the api is used. The former([gtk_combo_box_text_remove](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkComboBoxText.html#gtk-combo-box-text-remove)) is more up to date).

[gtk_combo_box_get_active](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkComboBox.html#gtk-combo-box-get-active) returns -1 if there is no active item and should therefore be checked before passing it to one of the remove functions. This is especially important if, as in the case presented above, the removing happens in a signal handler. According to the [documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk2/stable/GtkComboBox.html#GtkComboBox-changed) the "changed" signal

> [...] is emitted when the active item is changed. This can be due to the user selecting a different item from the list, or due to a call to gtk_combo_box_set_active_iter(). It will also be emitted while typing into the entry of a combo box with an entry. [...]

As far as i understand this includes when the item is deselected(which will presumably happen if it is deleted).

Your handler should therefore look somehow like this:

```
void combo_selected(GtkComboBox *widget, gpointer user_data)
{
    int active_id=gtk_combo_box_get_active(GTK_COMBO_BOX(combo));
    if(active_id!=-1)
    {
        //do real work...
    }
}
```

Comment: I did a similar solution over here using iter and GtkTreeModel: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39647258/999943